# What is the namespace 'Standard'?

Tags: c#, namespaces, using-directives

When I try to write a new `using` clause, I notice that Intellisense has, in its list, a namespace called `Standard`. However, this seems to have no members on closer inspection. What is this namespace?

Comment: It it part of your own project?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure, as I opened up another project, and it was still there. EDIT: It seems to appear in EVERY WPF project, but not on any other projects.

Comment: I can confirm it seems like a valid namespace on my machine too, putting a `using Standard;` doesn't cause any errors in a WPF application

Comment: I don't see it when I start a new WPF application, and get a build error if I try to use it anyway.  Using Studio 2010 / .NET 4.

Comment: @JeremyWiggins Seems to be a 4.5 namespace, according to the answer.

Comment: Try searching for 'standard' in Visual Studio's object browser (found under the 'view' menu)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a namespace in the PresentationFramework assembly called "Standard". All of its types are internal though, so you can't see any of the types. However, you can still use the namespace.

The namespace seems to have appeared in the 4.5 reference assembly, it doesn't appear in the 4.0 one.

[image]

Comment: @BoltClock wait till you see the wallpaper.