# .NET 4.5 namespace 'Standard'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, namespaces, c++-cli

In `PresentationFramework` from .NET 4.5 there is a namespace called `Standard`. Look here for more info: [What is the namespace 'Standard'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027084/what-is-the-namespace-standard)

The problem is that in my C++/CLI project I am using an unmanaged library, which also defines a class called `Standard`. So I get the following compiler error:

```
error C2869: 'Standard' : has already been defined to be a namespace
```

I cannot remove the reference to `PresentationFramework`, and I cannot stop using the said library. Is there anything I can do? Like un-importing the namespace?

P.S. I am using VisualStudio 2012. I think that an upgrade to 2013 might help, but that will require the whole team to move to it.

Comment: Are you using OCCT by any chance? How did you work around the problem?

Comment: we ended up making sure to not use both PresentationFramework and OCCT in the same project

Comment: ah, ic. I also succeeded doing so for quite a while but now reached a point where it's just too much overhead. So for anyone having the same problems, wrapping this Standard class in a namespace doesn't take too long and isn't much maintenance overhead - see https://dev.opencascade.org/index.php?q=node/1210

Answer (score 2):

That namespace was added to PresentationFramework by .NET 4.5, I believe, and I don't think changing to Visual Studio 2013 will help you.  Everything in that namespace is defined as internal, and it mostly consists of Enums and Structs used with Windows SDK functions called by PresentationFramework.

Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do about your problem.  Perhaps you can convince whoever supplies the third-party library to change *their* namespace.  The fact that Microsoft is now using it would be a good reason for them to do so.  Whoever these people are that are creating namespaces with a simple, generic name such as "Standard" need to have their heads examined.

Comment: I don't think the `Standard` namespace is a problem. A class called `Standard` though is a lot more egregious.